# How to average multiple GeoTIFF images?

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, geoprocessing, rasterio

To be short: how can I average two (or more) GeoTIFF images?

Explaining: I'm working with coastal water turbidity, using NASA Worldview images. I can easily visualize them in Jupyter Lab (Windows 10) and separated the RGB bands, and averaged them individually. My doubt is how to build a new GeoTIFF from the averaged bands? and keeping the spatial properties (lat/lon)?

My goal is to have a sort of monthly averaged images, and the standard deviation as well...

So far I'm doing this to understand how to do. Later I'll make it more functional for a  large number of images:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show

im1 = r'snapshot-2020-09-22T00_00_00Z.tiff'
im2 = r'snapshot-2020-09-29T00_00_00Z.tiff'

img1 = rasterio.open(im1)
img2 = rasterio.open(im2)

# selecting and averaging a band
b11 = img1.read(1)
b12 = img2.read(1)

b1m = (b11 + b12)/2
```

Comment: You can open a new dataset for writing using the source profile so it inherits all of the source properties.  See here for an example:  https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/writing.html

Answer (score 1):

Below, I show you how to average the band 1 and to save the result in a new raster with the same properties as another raster (projection, extension, etc). You can write a function and repeat the same process with a loop for several bands. But first, please try it with a single band. Just to make sure everything is running okay.

```
import gdal

rasternames=['snapshot-2020-09-22T00_00_00Z.tiff','snapshot-2020-09-29T00_00_00Z.tiff']

img1 = gdal.Open(rasternames[0])
img2 = gdal.Open(rasternames[1])

col   = img1.RasterXSize
rows  = img1.RasterYSize
driver = img1.GetDriver()

v1val = img1.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray().flatten()
v2val = img2.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray().flatten()

#calculate the average-data
avg = (v1val + v2val)/2
avgdataMatrix= avg.reshape(rows,col)

#here you will create a new raster to save the average-data

#this is a new raster just with 1 band. But you can repeat the process or even you can use a for loop. 
raster_avg = driver.Create("name_raster_avg" + ".tif", col, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
#here you copy the properties from another raster.
raster_avg.SetGeoTransform(img1.GetGeoTransform())
raster_avg.SetProjection(img1.GetProjection())

#finally, you add the avg data to your new raster

raster_avg.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(avgdataMatrix)
raster_avg.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(-99999)

#close the raster in order yo open in Qgis o Arcgis without problems.
raster_avg = None
del raster_avg
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work on rasterio, try as follows.
The following code assumes all rasters have same crs, resolution, extents.

```
from rasterio.plot import show
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import rasterio

im1 = 'im1.tif'
im2 = 'im2.tif'
im3 = 'im3.tif'

# Read source raster data and plot
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3)

with rasterio.open(im1) as src:
    array1 = src.read()
    profile1 = src.profile
    rasterio.plot.show(src, ax=axs[0])
with rasterio.open(im2) as src:
    array2 = src.read()
    profile2 = src.profile
    rasterio.plot.show(src, ax=axs[1])
with rasterio.open(im3) as src:
    array3 = src.read()
    profile3 = src.profile
    rasterio.plot.show(src, ax=axs[2])
```

[image: preview_data]

```
# Create nodata mask (True is nodata)
nodata_mask = np.any((array1 == profile1.get('nodata'),
                      array2 == profile2.get('nodata'),
                      array3 == profile3.get('nodata')),
                     axis=0)
# Compute anything what you want
array_mean = np.mean((array1, array2, array3), axis=0)
array_sd = np.std((array1, array2, array3), axis=0)

# replace nodata pixels to np.nan
array_mean[nodata_mask] = np.nan
array_sd[nodata_mask] = np.nan

# Plot in matplotlib
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3)
axs = axs.flatten()
axs[0].matshow(array1[0])
axs[1].matshow(array2[0])
axs[2].matshow(array3[0])
axs[3].matshow(nodata_mask[0])
axs[4].matshow(array_mean[0])
axs[5].matshow(array_sd[0])
```

[image: plot products]

```
# Write as geotiff file
profile_out = profile1.copy()
profile_out.update(dtype=array_mean.dtype.name,
                   nodata=np.nan)
with rasterio.open('out.tif', 'w', **profile_out) as dst:
    dst.write(array_mean)
```